# Rails, Deleting Children without Deleting Parent using :has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, children, has-many

I have

```
class MyContainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  :has_many MyObjects, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I want to delete all the `MyObjects` in the container without having to delete the `MyContainer`. My model does have `:dependent => :destroy`, however I don't want to have to delete and re-create the object because it is slower.

Something like this does not work:

```
@obj = MyContainer.find_by_id(10)
@obj.my_objects.delete_all
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002275) is an `ActiveRecord::Base` class method.

You should use [`destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002274). Something like:

```
@container = MyContainer.find_by_id(10)
@container.my_objects.destroy_all
```

---

Using `delete_all` properly would be faster if you don't need to lookup your `MyContainer` first (or use it for other stuff)

```
MyObject.delete_all(["my_container_id = ?", 10])
```

---

EDIT: for rails 3

```
MyObject.where(my_container_id: 10).delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

One or both of these should work:

```
MyContainer.find(10).my_objects.destroy_all

MyContainer.find(10).my_objects.each(&:destroy)
```

Comment: Using the latter, solution would load each object into memory and be slow. Probably want to go with first solution.

Comment: Both with instantiate each object into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete objects directly like following

```
MyObject.delete_all(["my_container_id=?", 10])
```